# UWP - Image doesn't change content when image file it references to are change

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to take video snapshot and preview it by a scroller. Assumed that we have `bohemian.mp4`, my app would take snapshot at some point and save to `bohemian.png`. Here's mentioned part.

**xaml:**

```cs
<Image x:Name="thumbnail" CacheMode="BitmapCache"
                   MinHeight="200" MaxHeight="400" Margin="0,20,0,0" Stretch="Uniform" 
                   Source="{x:Bind mp3ViewerViewModel.mp3ViewerModel.ImagePath, Mode=OneWay}"/>

<Slider x:Name="SnapshotSlider"
                            Minimum="0" Maximum="{x:Bind mp3ViewerViewModel.mp3ViewerModel.Duration}"
                            Value="{x:Bind mp3ViewerViewModel.mp3ViewerModel.Snapshot}"
                            IsEnabled="{x:Bind mp3ViewerViewModel.mp3ViewerModel.UseSnapshot, Mode=OneWay}"
                            />

<Button x:Name="SaveButton"
                    RelativePanel.Below="detailGrid" RelativePanel.AlignRightWith="detailGrid"
                    Foreground="White" BorderBrush="#FF004CFF" Background="#FF0096FF" 
                    Content="Save As"
                    Command="{x:Bind mp3ViewerViewModel.UpdateSnapshotCmd}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=SnapshotSlider, Path=Value}"/>
```

For debugging purpose, I would let `Button` handle my `Command`

**View Model:**

```
public CommandEventHandler<double> UpdateSnapshotCmd
        {
            get
            {
                return new CommandEventHandler<double>(
                    async (second) => await UpdateSnapshotPreview(second)
                    );
            }
        }

public async Task UpdateSnapshotPreview(double second)
        {
            try
            {
                if (mp4 == null)
                {
                    mp4 = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(mp4Path);
                }

                var imgName = Path.ChangeExtension(mp4.Name, ".png");

                StorageFile imgFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync(imgName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                MediaComposition mediaComposition = new MediaComposition();
                MediaClip mediaClip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(mp4);
                mediaComposition.Clips.Add(mediaClip);
                
                var interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(second);
                var thumbnail = await mediaComposition.GetThumbnailAsync(interval, 
                    1024, 768, VideoFramePrecision.NearestKeyFrame);

                using (var randomAccess = await imgFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                using (var destStream = randomAccess.AsStream())
                using (var sourceStream = thumbnail.AsStream())
                {
                    await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destStream);
                }

                mp3ViewerModel.ImagePath = imgFile.Path;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await new MessageDialog(ex.Message).ShowAsync();
            }
            
        }
```

**Model:**

```cs
        string imagePath = "/Assets/default_thumbnail.jpg";
        string defaultImg = "/Assets/default_thumbnail.jpg";
        public string ImagePath 
        {
            get
            {
                if (UseSnapshot)
                    return imagePath;
                else
                    return defaultImg;
            }
            set
            {
                imagePath = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

When I checked saved folder, `png` file was changed as `Slider.Value` but `Image` in the app just responsed once. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think because file path remains unchanged so that lead to `Image` behaves the same despite of different content or `OnPropertyChanged` invoke.

Therefore, I come to a solution which is in **ViewModel:**

```cs
StorageFile imgFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync(imgName, 
CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Change to:

```cs
StorageFile imgFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync(imgName, 
CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
```

However, this will create a bunch of `png` and look ugly. I wonder if there any alternative solution that I could re-use the first and only `png`?

Comment: That's correct, I suggest to use decoded image to bind to view and that way you also don't have to save image to file just create  a image source variable and assigne value to it and bind the same  so when slider changes the image source can directly be update without saving to file

Answer (score 0):

Use a [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netcore-3.1) to watch for when a file changes:

Answer (score 0):

i think this because Image does some caching internally so you have to explicitly set CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache

in my case:
service Task

```
public async Task<BitmapImage> TakePhotoAsync()
{
    if (IsInitialized && IsPreviewing && !IsRecordiing)
    {
        try
        {
            var file = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("photo.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            await mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), file);

            return new BitmapImage
            {
                UriSource = new Uri(file.Path),
                CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

ViewModel Property

```
private ImageSource photoImage;
public ImageSource PhotoImage
{
    get => photoImage;
    set => SetProperty(ref photoImage, value);
}
```

ViewModel Command to get image

```
public RelayCommand TakePhotoCommand { get; set; }
```

ViewModel Constructor

```
TakePhotoCommand = new RelayCommand(async () => PhotoImage = await CameraService.TakePhotoAsync());
```

Image Binding

```
<Image Source="{x:Bind ViewModel.PhotoImage, Mode=OneWay}/>
```

---

So basically you have yo change:

```
string ImagePath
```

to

```
ImageSource ImagePath
```

and

```
ImagePath = new BitmapImage
{
     UriSource = new Uri(imgFile.Path),
     CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache
}
```

Hope that helps